# Do we have a tag for user defined commands questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently, tags containing the word `command` on our site are the following:

- [command-line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line) for questions about ex mode commands (accessed with `:`).
- [external-command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-command) for questions about calling shell tools within vim.
- [command-history](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-history) for questions about the ex mode history.
- [command-line-window](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line-window) for question about the window accessed via `q:`.
- And [repeated-commands](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeated-commands) whose wiki isn't defined but which contains questions about the global command, macros and repeating stuff.

**My question is**: Is one of these tags appropriated for questions about user-defined commands? What I'm talking about is especially questions about the keyword `command` which allows to define commands that can be used in ex mode.

I might have missed the tag I'm talking about or misunderstood one (or several) of the tags I mentioned earlier, but I have the feeling that such a tag is missing.

The reason I am thinking about it and asking this question is that I saw several questions which could benefit of a dedicated tag, here are some example:

- [Filtering text out to new tab with custom command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4426/1841) which is about creating a command taking a pattern as argument and is tagged [vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vimrc) and [buffers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffers).
- [How to define a custom user defined command to filter a range?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3374/1841) which is about creating a command taking a range and is tagged [external-command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-command).
- [How to design a command in a plugin that can be called from vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2791/1841) which is about using a user-defined command defined in a plugin from the `vimrc`. Tagged [command-line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line) (and also [vimscript](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vimscript) and [plugin-system](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-system) but that is coherent with a part of the question).
- [Is there a command to enter Visual Block mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3699/1841) which is not the best example but could also be tagged with a dedicated tag.

**Also** if we find out that this tag really doesn't exist and that it would be useful to the site, it would be good to decide how to call this new tag. I think that something like `user-defined-command` would be nice to avoid confusion with the already existing ones.

Comment: [tag:commmand-command] :-)

Comment: There's also [tag:command-mode], which is an alias for [tag:normal-mode] by the way.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I don't see `commmand-command` neither `command-command` was you kidding or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it was a joke ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Oh okay! I like the 3 `m` version then :-)

Answer (score 6):

Unlike the two other sites I regularly participate in (Ask Ubuntu and Unix & Linux), we don't have many tags for specific commands. Ones like [split](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/split) and [highlight](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/highlight) cover a set of related commands, which include eponymous commands. I propose that if we do add a tag for user-defined commands, we name it after the help tag for those: [`user-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#user-commands).

This tag would also cover the related `:delc[ommand]` and `:comc[lear]` commands.

Comment: It is unfortunate that a `:` is not allowed in tag names. Otherwise we could create a `:command` tag. Perhaps a generic prefix (such as `cmd-`) might be a good idea? `cmd-command`, `cmd-split`, `cmd-highlight`? Not sure if that would be obvious enough though...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker we can hope that users read the tag excerpt...

Comment: I guess that if `split` and `highlight` are important enough to have a tag then `command` is too, right? Also I really approve the `cmd-` prefix it would clarify the already existing tags.

Comment: @statox I think you misunderstood that line. `:split` and `:highlight` don't have their own tags. `split` and `highlight` as classes of commands/actions do.

Comment: @muru Oh right I misunderstood it. But I approve your edit: it would make sense that the tag covers the related commands.

Comment: @statox given the relative lack of activity on meta, I'll wait around for a score of (completely arbitrarily decided) 5 before making the tag. Sounds good?

Comment: @muru as you wish, you're the mod ;-) let's us know when the tag is created, I'll gladly help retagging the questions I mentioned and searching for other ones which could benefit of the new tag.

Comment: @statox I got bored and created it.

Comment: @muru: Cool thanks a lot! It's too bad that meta isn't active enough to have gathered a 5th vote... Btw I'll edit the questions I mentionned and maybe see if other can be relevant.

Comment: @statox I applied the tag to two mentioned, but left the other two alone (not so sure about them).

Comment: @muru: Yep that's what I just saw... I'm also not sure about the 3rd one now but I think the one about the command to enter visual mode is ok for this tag.

Comment: @statox add a wiki/excerpt too, if you can

Comment: @muru: Yup I'm on it :-)